# Passing score variable to another swf with LocalConnection using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have three games - swf1, swf2 and swf3. I need to pass the score variable from swf1 into swf2 in order to combine those scores. Then, I need to pass the swf1 & swf2 newly combined scores into swf3 so that I can total scores from all three games combined. I am using a Loader class to link the swfs together and I am attempting to use LocalConnection to pass the score variables with no luck.

**Swf1: (sending swf)**

```
package
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.LocalConnection; // import/export score *************************************************

public class Map extends MovieClip
{
    var errorCount = 0;
    var dragdrops: Array;
    var numOfMatches: uint = 0; 
    var speed: Number = 25; 
    var eventSound: event_sound = new event_sound();
    var winSound: winner = new winner();
    // Send score from this swf into swf 2. *************************************************
    var send_score:LocalConnection;

    public function Map()
    {
        dragdrops = [i_double, i_triple, i_increase, i_reduce, i_diamonds, i_skus, i_platinums, i_abos, i_50, i_2020, i_2025, i_10000]; 
        var currentObject: DragDrop;
        for (var i: uint = 0; i < dragdrops.length; i++) 
        {
            currentObject = dragdrops[i];
            currentObject.target = getChildByName(currentObject.name + "_target");
        }
        start.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startGame);
    }

    function startGame(event: Event): void
    {
        start.y -= speed;
        if (start.y <= 0)
        {
            start.y = 0;
            start.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startGame); 
            start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickStart) 
        }
    }

    function clickStart(event: MouseEvent): void
    {
        start.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickStart) 
        start.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateUp); 
        eventSound.play();
        addChild(start); 
    }

    function animateUp(event: Event): void
    {
        start.y -= speed;
        if (start.y >= stage.stageHeight)
        {
            start.y = stage.stageHeight; 
            start.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateUp); 
        }
    }

    public function match(): void 
    {
        numOfMatches++;
        if (numOfMatches == 3) 
        {
            win.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, winGame);

        }
    }

    function winGame(event: Event): void 
    {
        var errorCount_Game1 = errorCount;

        if( win.playerErrorText.text != String( errorCount_Game1 ) ) {
            win.playerErrorText.text = String( errorCount_Game1 );
        }

        // Send swf1 score to next swf2 game. ***************************************************************
        send_score = new LocalConnection();
        send_score.send('myConnection', 'methodtoexecute', errorCount_Game1);

        win.y -= speed;
        if (win.y <= 0)
        {
            win.y = 0; // move win screen to top position.
            win.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, winGame); 
            win.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, nextGame); 
            winSound.play();
        }
    }


    function nextGame(event: MouseEvent): void  
    {
        var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Game2.swf"); 
        myLoader.load(url);                                     
        addChild(myLoader);                                     
    }
}
}
```

**Swf2: (receiving & sending swf)**

```
package
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.LocalConnection; // to import/export score

public class Map2 extends MovieClip
{
    var errorCount = 0;
    var dragdrops: Array;
    var numOfMatches: uint = 0; 
    var speed: Number = 25; 
    var eventSound: event_sound = new event_sound();
    var winSound: winner = new winner();

    // Load score from swf1 into this swf2 game *************************************************
    var get_score:LocalConnection;

    public function Map2()
    {
        dragdrops = [i_energize, i_experience, i_growth, i_increase, i_renewabo, i_partner, i_share, i_winat, i_winwith]; 
        var currentObject: DragDrop;
        for (var i: uint = 0; i < dragdrops.length; i++) 
        {
            currentObject = dragdrops[i];
            currentObject.target = getChildByName(currentObject.name + "_target");
        }
    }

    function startGame(event: Event): void
    {
        start.y -= speed;
        if (start.y <= 0)
        {
            start.y = 0; 
            start.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startGame); 
            start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickStart) 
        }
    }

    function clickStart(event: MouseEvent): void
    {
        start.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickStart) 
        start.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateUp); 
        eventSound.play();
        addChild(start); 
    }

    function animateUp(event: Event): void
    {
        start.y -= speed;
        if (start.y >= stage.stageHeight)
        {
            start.y = stage.stageHeight; 
            start.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateUp); 
        }
    }

    public function match(): void 
    {
        numOfMatches++;
        if (numOfMatches == 3)
        {
            win.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, winGame);
        }
    }

    function winGame(event: Event): void 
    {
        // Load score from swf 1 into this swf2 game. *************************************************
        get_score = new LocalConnection();
        get_score.methodtoexecute = function(errorCount_Game1) 
        {
            errorCount_Game2 = errorCount + errorCount_Game1;
        }
        get_score.connect('myConnection');

        if( win.playerErrorText.text != String( errorCount_Game2 ) ) {
            win.playerErrorText.text = String( errorCount_Game2 );
        }

        win.y -= speed;
        if (win.y <= 0)
        {
            win.y = 0; 
            win.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, winGame); 
            win.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, nextGame); 
            winSound.play();
        }

        // Send this combined swf2 score to next swf3 game. ***************************************************************
        send_score = new LocalConnection();
        send_score.send('myConnection', 'methodtoexecute', errorCount_Game2);
    }

    function nextGame(event: MouseEvent): void  
    {
        var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Game3.swf"); 
        myLoader.load(url);                                     
        addChild(myLoader);                                     
    }
}
}
```

**Swf3: (receiving swf)**

```
package
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.LocalConnection; // import/export score

public class Map3 extends MovieClip
{
    var errorCount = 0;
    var dragdrops: Array;
    var numOfMatches: uint = 0; 
    var speed: Number = 25; 
    var eventSound:event_sound = new event_sound();
    var winSound:winner = new winner();
    var miss_drop: uint = 0; 

    // Load combined scores from swf2 into this swf3 *************************************************
    var get_final_score:LocalConnection;

    public function Map3()
    {
        dragdrops = [i_positive, i_integrated, i_rewards, i_leaderdev, i_leaderalign, i_focused, i_fast, i_fun];
        var currentObject: DragDrop;
        for (var i: uint = 0; i < dragdrops.length; i++) 
        {
            currentObject = dragdrops[i];
            currentObject.target = getChildByName(currentObject.name + "_target");
        }
    }


    function startGame(event: Event): void
    {
        start.y -= speed;
        if (start.y <= 0)
        {
            start.y = 0; 
            start.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, startGame); 
            start.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickStart) 
        }
    }

    function clickStart(event: MouseEvent): void
    {
        start.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickStart) 
        start.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateUp); 
        eventSound.play();
        addChild(start);
    }

    function animateUp(event: Event): void
    {
        start.y -= speed;
        if (start.y >= stage.stageHeight)
        {
            start.y = stage.stageHeight; 
            start.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animateUp); 
        }
    }

    public function match():void
    {
        numOfMatches++;
        if(numOfMatches == dragdrops.length)
        {
            win.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, winGame);
        }
    }

    function winGame(event: Event): void
    {
        get_final_score = new LocalConnection();
        get_final_score.methodtoexecute = function(errorCount_Game2) 
        {
            errorCount_Game3 = errorCount + errorCount_Game2;
        }
        get_score.connect('myConnection');

        if( win.playerErrorText.text != String( errorCount_Game3 ) ) {
            win.playerErrorText.text = String( errorCount_Game3 );
        }

        win.y -= speed;
        if (win.y <= 0)
        {
            win.y = 0; 
            win.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, winGame); 
            //win.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickWin) 
            win.replay_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, nextGame);  
            winSound.play();
            missDrop();
        }
    }

    public function missDrop():void
    {
        if (errorCount_Game3 == 0 || errorCount_Game3 == 1)
        {
            win.fourstars.alpha = 1;        
        }
        else if (errorCount_Game3 == 2 || errorCount_Game3 == 3)
        {
            win.threestars.alpha = 1;   
        }
        else if (errorCount_Game3 == 4 || errorCount_Game3 == 5)
        {
            win.twostars.alpha = 1; 
        }
        else if (errorCount_Game3 > 5)
        {
            win.onestar.alpha = 1; 
        }
    }

    function nextGame(event: MouseEvent): void
    {
        var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Game1.swf"); 
        myLoader.load(url);                                     
        addChild(myLoader);                                     
    }
}
}
```

**Class that increments score for all swfs**

```
package
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class DragDrop extends Sprite
{
    var origX: Number;
    var origY: Number;
    var target: DisplayObject;
    var successSound:sound_correct = new sound_correct();

    public function DragDrop()
    {
        origX = x; 
        origY = y;
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
        buttonMode = true; 
    }

    function drag(evt: MouseEvent): void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
        startDrag();
    }

    function drop(evt: MouseEvent): void
    {
        var n = (evt.target.name).split('i_').join('');
        var s = 'null';
        var isit = false;
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, drop);
        stopDrag();

        if (hitTestObject(target)) 
        {
            visible = false; 
            target.alpha = 1; 
            successSound.play();
            //run match method (within the Map Class file)
            Object(parent).match();

            isit = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var list = Object(parent).dragdrops;
            Object(parent).errorCount++; // Increments scoring
            for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                var o = MovieClip(root).getChildByName(list[i].name + '_target');
                if (o.hitTestObject(evt.target))
                {
                    var temp = o.name.split('i_').join('');
                    temp = temp.split('_target').join('');
                    s = temp
                }
            }
        }
        x = origX; 
        y = origY;
    }
}
}
```

I am hoping someone can recognize the error that I am making with the code so that I can properly pass the score variable into each respective swf as the games progress along.  Currently swf1 plays through perfect then once swf2 loads I receive the error message "Error #2044: Unhandled StatusEvent:. level=error, code=" several times in a row.

Thank you for any help you might be able to provide with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass an information between two swfs, you can use a [`LocalConnection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html) or a [`LoaderContext`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/LoaderContext.html) object.

**Using LocalConnection object :**

**game_01.swf :**

```
var game01_score:int = 1000;

var connection:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    // you have to wait until the swf is completly loaded
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _onLoad);
    function _onLoad(e:Event): void {
        // send game01_score to game_02.swf
        connection.send('Game01_To_Game02', 'get_Game01_Score', game01_score);
    }
    loader.load(new URLRequest('game_02.swf')); 
addChild(loader);
```

**game_02.swf :**

```
var game02_score:int = 800;

// LocalConnection to receive game01_score from game_01.swf
var game01_connection:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
    game01_connection.client = this;
    game01_connection.connect('Game01_To_Game02');
    function get_Game01_Score(game01_score:String):void {
        trace(game01_score);    // gives : 1000
        game02_score += int(game01_score);
        trace(game02_score);    // gives : 1800
        // load the game_03.swf after receiving game01_score
        loader.load(new URLRequest('game_03.swf'));
    }

// LocalConnection to send game01_score + game02_score to game_03.swf
var game03_connection:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _onLoad);
    function _onLoad(e:Event): void {
        // send game02_score ( game01_score + game02_score ) to game_03.swf
        game03_connection.send('Game02_To_Game03', 'get_Game02_Score', game02_score);
    }   
addChild(loader);
```

**game_03.swf :**

```
// LocalConnection to receive game02_score from game_02.swf
var game02_connection:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
    game02_connection.client = this;
    game02_connection.connect('Game02_To_Game03');
    function get_Game02_Score(game02_score:String):void {
        trace(game02_score);    // gives : 1800
    }
```

---

**Using LoaderContext object :**

**game_01.swf :**

```
var game01_score:int = 1000;

var loader_context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    // pass game01_score via the LoaderContext
    loader_context.parameters = { 'game01_score' : game01_score.toString() };

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest('game_02.swf'), loader_context);
    addChild(loader);
```

**game_02.swf :**

```
var game02_score:int = 800;
    // get game01_score from game_01.swf
    game02_score += int(this.loaderInfo.parameters.game01_score) || 0;

trace(game02_score);    // gives : 1800

var loader_context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
    loader_context.parameters = { 'game02_score' : game02_score.toString() };

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest('game_03.swf'), loader_context);
    addChild(loader);
```

**game_03.swf :**

```
trace(this.loaderInfo.parameters.game02_score || '0');  // gives : 1800
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Wonderful!  I followed your guidance with using LoaderContext object. I import flash.system.LoaderContext;  and placed the code and it worked!!!  Thanks so very much for your assistance with this! I now see why I was so confused before. Thanks again!