# Load and Communicate with external SWFs in a different windows in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a SWF that i would like to be projected (literally) to a crowd. However, I would like to make some sort of Control Panel to control the contents of the SWF, that the audience wont be able to see. [Currently, I have all of the controls on the bottom of the screen and i just put a piece of tape over the projector...]

Is there any way to have 2 separate SWFs in separate windows (Windows Projectors .exe) so I can have one maximized on the secondary monitor (Projector) and one on my Laptop's Screen - to control it.

Comment: For that, you can try a [`LocalConnection`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html), take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29371078/2256820) for a very simple example ...

Comment: You could also use AIR instead of a projector. With AIR you can simply have 2 windows in a single app and communicating between windows is very easy.